# TelegramBot. Как редактировать свои сообщения?

Tags: java

Есть библиотека от rubenlagus. Вопрос в следующем, как отредактировать сообщения которые отправляет бот? Т.е свои же. Есть в библиотеке EditMessageText для таких случаев. Но получаю ошибку: Error editing message text: [400] Bad Request: message can't be edited.

Вот так отправляю:

```
private void sendEmptyMessage(long chat_id,String message, String marker)
 {
     if(message.isEmpty()){message = "-";}
     SendMessage sendMessage = new  SendMessage().setChatId(chat_id).setText(message);

     this.marker = marker; 

     try { execute(sendMessage);} catch (TelegramApiException ex) {System.out.println("Error emptySendMessage to ID:\t"+chat_id+"\nError: "+ex.getMessage());  }
}
```

В обработчике

```
(update.hasMessage() && update.getMessage().hasText())
```

код

```
if (marker.equalsIgnoreCase("runsysteminfo"))
        {
           tempName = update.getMessage().getMessageId();
           System.out.println("ID: "+tempName);
           sendEmptyMessage(chat_id, "⌛ Подключение",""); 
         }
```

ID выводится четырехзначное. Значить получает. Но когда дальше я пытаюсь изменить таким кодом

```
EditMessageText editMessage = new EditMessageText();
                        editMessage.setChatId(chat_id);
                        editMessage.setMessageId(tempName);
                        editMessage.setText("text"); 
                        try {
                            editMessageText(editMessage);
                        } catch (TelegramApiException ex){}
```

то получаю ошибку: Error editing message text: [400] Bad Request: message can't be edited.
Может есть у кого-то пример с данной библиотекой для изменения сообщений? Или почему ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

Сложно анализировать код, который такими кусками, но мне кажется, что тут проблема в логики, и ты пробуешь изменить чужое сообщение, потому что получаешь `tempName` из апдейта. 
Происходит следующее:

1. Ты посылаешь сообщение боту
2. Элемент списка
3. Он тебе отвечает на это с "Подключение"
4. Ты посылаешь ему сообщение в ответ
5. Он записывает `messageId` пункта 4. и пытается править
6. Вываливается ошибка

Тебе нужно запоминать айди именно того сообщение, которое нужно править, а не ответного или другого.

Comment: В общем почитал, и понял, редактировать можно только инлайн сообщения. Т.е по сути текст в встроенной кнопке. А вот обычный получается что нельзя. Поправьте меня если не прав.

Comment: Да вроде нет такого ограничения. Там написано: Please note, that it is currently only possible to edit messages without reply_markup or with inline keyboards. Т.е. можно обычные сообщения, но отправленные без reply_markup

Comment: Как раз обычные кнопки никак невозможно редактировать, только послать сигнал на их скрытые, можно редактировать сообщение с инлайн кнопками меняя тем самым любой компонент сообщения (инлайн кнопки, текст, изображение)

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно получать ID и в дальнейшем его редактировать:

```
private long sendEmptyMessage(long chat_id,String message, String marker)
{
     if(message.isEmpty()){message = "-";}
     SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage().setChatId(chat_id).setText(message);

     this.marker = marker; 
     long messageID = 0;
     try { messageID = execute(sendMessage).getMessageId(); }
     catch (TelegramApiException ex) {System.out.println("Error emptySendMessage to ID:\t"+chat_id+"\nError: "+ex.getMessage());  }
     return messageID;
}
```