# Как редактировать Reply клавиатуру или как выводить другую. Telegram бот на Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Вторая клавиатура не выводится.

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('токен мой')
keyboard1 = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, True)
keyboard1.row('Информация')
keyboard2 = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, True)
keyboard2.row('1', '2', '3')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет', reply_markup=keyboard1)
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_text(message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'Привет':
        bot.edit_message_reply_markup(message.chat.id, message.message_id, 'Выбери:', reply_markup=keyboard2)


bot.polling()
```

Comment: Пробовал удалять первую клавиатуру через ReplyKeyboardRemove. Вторая все равно не выводится.

Comment: Нашел как редактировать inline клаву, но она не такая классная как Reply. Хочу научиться делать интерактивное меню именно через Reply, как например на телеграм-боте Worki

Comment: Поменял, но суть не меняет, клавиатура не добавляется.

Answer (score 3):

`@bot.message_handler(commands=['text'])` замени на `@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])` во втором случае

> Поменял, но суть не меняет, клавиатура не добавляется.

ошибка в условии: `message.text.lower() == 'Привет'` не сработает, так как текст сообщения "Привет" переводится в "привет" благодаря lower(). Замени `'Привет'` на `'привет'`, дабы условие срабатывало

Answer (score 3):

`message.text.lower() == 'Привет'` не будет работать, потому что сравнивать, допустим `message.text = привет` с `Привет` как-то неправильно)

а так, ваш код нужно поправить до:

```
if message.text.lower() == 'привет':
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'ну Привет', reply_markup=keyboard2)
```

и кнопка "Информация" будет заменена на кнопки "1", "2", "3" после отправки боту "привет"

[здесь в комментариях к ответу как раз пришли к выводу что обычные кнопки редактировать нельзя](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/816812/234134)